# What does "sites" mean in the lattice language?

Tags: terminology, definition, lattice-model

I acknowledge that this question is quite trivial. But in the lattice jargon, what does a $N$-sites lattice mean?

- it's a lattice $N\times N$ or
- it's a lattice with $N$ vertices?
- another option perhaps.

From the context I cannot infer it. I just know that $N$ is quite large, i.e. in the thermodynamic limit $N\to \infty$, one also has $N^2\to\infty$ and $N^{1/2}\to\infty$.

---

*Edit:* The lattice is in 2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Site" is synonymous with "vertex". They're called "sites" because they're the places where the objects of interest (particles with a spin or whatever) are located. So it's a lattice with $N$ vertices.

Comment: Ok, so, for a finite $d$-dim lattice with $N$ sites, if equally spacially distributed, you got a $N^{1/d}\times\ldots\times N^{1/d}$ array, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, though I guess in general it could be some shape other than a $d$-cube.